# python process pause&resume

Tags: python, process, fastapi

I received the ffmpeg command command and executed it like "ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command)".

Now, I want to add a function to temporarily suspend and resume the execution of a command through a button on the webpage.

It was possible to find the id through ffmpeg_process.pid and confirm through the log until the button was executed.
However, the process does not stop and continues to run.

What could be the reason... If the method is wrong, please tell me!

---

```
import subprocess
import threading



from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Depends, Request, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

from modules.websocket_manager import WebSocketManager

import os
import json
import cv2
import psutil
import signal
import ctypes


PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME = 0x0800


from ultralytics import YOLO



router = APIRouter()
app = FastAPI()

ws_manager = WebSocketManager()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")




ffmpeg_process = None
paused = False  
ffmpeg_thread = None





@router.get("/ffmpeg", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def model(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("VidSend.html", context={"request": request})




@router.post("/ffmpeg/Send")
async def run_ffmpeg(request: Request):

    selectedcam = request.query_params.get("selectedcam", "")
    selectedvid = request.query_params.get("selectedvid", "")
    
    global ffmpeg_process
    global paused

    ffmpeg_command = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-ss', '50',                         
        '-i', selectedvid,                 
        '-c:v', 'libx264',                    
        '-preset', 'medium',                 
        '-b:v', '8000k',                      
        '-f', 'flv',                         
        selectedcam      #'rtmp://localhost/live/livetest '
    ]
    
    ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command)

    paused = False  



def suspend_process(pid):
    handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME, False, pid)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.DebugActiveProcess(handle)


def resume_process(pid):
    handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME, False, pid)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.DebugActiveProcessStop(handle)



@router.post("/pause")
async def pause():
    global ffmpeg_process
    global paused
    print(ffmpeg_process.pid)
    print(paused)
    if ffmpeg_process and not paused:
        suspend_process(ffmpeg_process.pid)
        paused = True




@router.post("/resume")
async def resume():
    global ffmpeg_process
    global paused
    print(ffmpeg_process)
    print(paused)
    
    if ffmpeg_process and paused:
        resume_process(ffmpeg_process.pid)
        paused = False
```

Answer (score -1):

The `ctypes.windll.kernel32.DebugActiveProcess` and `ctypes.windll.kernel32.DebugActiveProcessStop` calls you're using are meant for debugging processes and may not be suited for suspending and resuming processes in the context of what you're trying to do.

Instead, if you are running on a Unix-like operating system (e.g., Linux), you can send a `SIGSTOP` to suspend (pause) a process and `SIGCONT` to continue (resume) it. Here's how you can adjust your code:

Change the `suspend_process` and `resume_process` functions to use `os.kill`:

**python**

```
def suspend_process(pid):
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGSTOP)

def resume_process(pid):
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGCONT)
```

1. Make sure to import the required `signal` and `os` libraries (which you seem to already have).

Ensure you are running your code on a Unix-like OS. These signal commands will not work on Windows.

Another important note: If you ever decide to run this code on Windows, you will need a different approach. The Windows API does have a function for suspending and resuming threads (`SuspendThread` and `ResumeThread`), but using them can be tricky and may lead to unexpected behavior.

Also, before applying these signals, always ensure that you handle any potential side effects or data corruption that can arise when forcibly suspending a process, especially a process like `ffmpeg` that might be in the middle of writing data.